# Is it Possible to Mount a gzipped Partition Image?

Tags: linux, mount, disk-image

I created an image of an NTFS partition using:

`sudo dd if=/dev/sda3 | gzip -c > Windows.img.gz &`

Is there any way that I can mount the compressed image directly? I do not have the disk space to unzip the whole image to mount it.

If it's not possible, is there a better way to create a compressed image that would be directly mountable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.  Instead of using `dd` to create the image in the first place, use `ntfsclone`.  It is smart enough to skip the unused space.  Even if you don't compress the image, without all of the trash in the unused blocks, it will probably be smaller than the compressed `dd` image, and you can mount that image directly.

Answer (score 2):

No, not with `gzip` I'm afraid. The way gzip works it would be impossible to mount it as a block device. You could have used `squashfs` to compress your image. Sorry to bring you bad news but you can try with USB drive for example.